# combine 2 dataframes having different column names

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

In R ,I have 2 data frames both having different column name. I want to combine the rows of each data frame according to the column number. 
the dataframes i have is as follows

```
> d1
  X.0.52..V2 X.0.52..V4
1        ABT        700
2        AMD       9600
3        AMG        600
4       AGCO        800

> d2
  X.52.96..V2 X.52.96..V4
1        COMS      162193
2         MMM      419645
3          SE      146343
4        ADCT       62609
5         TCC        6623
```

I want the following dataframe:

```
 >d3

       ticker        value
 1        ABT         700
 2        AMD        9600
 3        AMG         600
 4       AGCO         800
 5       COMS      162193
 6        MMM      419645
 7         SE      146343
 8       ADCT       62609
 9        TCC        6623
```

what is the code i need to use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it's this simple I'd be inclined to use:

```
colnames(d1) <- colnames(d2) <- c("ticker", "value")
rbind.data.frame(d1, d2)
```

Answer (score 3):

If your actual situation is as simple as this, you can easily match the names from the two:

```
names(df2) <- names(df1)
```

Then `rbind` them together:

```
df.both <- rbind(df1, df2)
```

and give the dataframe the names you want:

```
names(df.both) <- c("ticker", "value")

# > df.both
# ticker  value
# 1     ABT    700
# 2     AMD   9600
# 3     AMG    600
# 4    AGCO    800
# 11   COMS 162193
# 21    MMM 419645
# 31     SE 146343
# 41   ADCT  62609
# 5     TCC   6623
```